# WCF Async operation not giving output

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

I am calling WCF Service in xamarin, below is my code

```
res = Task.Factory.FromAsync((asyncCallback, asyncState) =>
                               _client.BeginMagic(req, asyncCallback, asyncState),
                             (asyncResult) =>
                               _client.EndMagic(asyncResult),null ).Result;
```

if I use the Proxy class generated using Svcutil.exe this code gives perfect output. Now i have added ServiceReference to access the service.
but it is not giving me output. see the screenshot , it shows children could not be evaluated.

[image]

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your method name is `GetRecords()` then there might be an event exist like `GetRecordsCompleted` .You have to bind it if it exist.Because after referencing the WCF service in silverlight project, events are created for every service method.Try it but not sure in Xamarin.

Comment: This event is get fired when operation is completed and you can get the result from Result property of your EventArgument parameter like e

Comment: I have checked that too, its just giving me class name no data. "ClassLibrary1.UnityRef.MagicResponseMagicResult" this is the result but no data.